# preg_match exact world - no partial by array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

Hello everyone I made this php code

```
$variablename = "Marron";
$tallas = '#^/' . implode(array("XL", "L", "M", "S", "XS"), '|') . '/#';
if (preg_match($tallas, $variablename, $matchesatr)) {
$opciones = "Tallas";
} else {
$opciones = "Opciones";
}
```

Which results in M since it found the result M in the word `Marron`
You can check this in `$matchesatr`

The problem here is that I need my preg_match to be very exact that I just need it to only match the value "M" if there is only that word.

Currently if the value of the variable begins or contains M returns true as a result.

I need you to be very sensitive to explain myself better.

If you find the value M of as true result.

If you find a word that starts with M or contains M of false result.

Of course, I have an array of words to search for, which would be: `XL, L, M, S, XS`

Additional note: I also need it to be case insensitive eg to detect `"M" or "m"`

Comment: Try `$tallas = '#^(?:' . implode(array("XL", "L", "M", "S", "XS"), '|') . ')$#';` or `$tallas = '#\b(?:' . implode(array("XL", "L", "M", "S", "XS"), '|') . ')\b#';`

Comment: also change the order in implode, putting the separator `|` first

Comment: Dear @Wiktor Stribiżew the first thing works however it is case sensitive i need it not to be. PS: thanks for your time

Comment: Dear @The fourth bird before or after the array?  PS: thanks for your time

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Do you only want a match if the word is at the start of the string? Like https://3v4l.org/hmFFr ?

Comment: Solve the implode, thank you very much, the only thing missing is the non-sensitivity to capital letters.

Comment: `$tallas = '#^(?:' . implode('|', array("XL", "L", "M", "S", "XS")) . ')(?!\S)#i';`
Thank you very much it works now thanks to your help! thanks to all! @The fourth bird
 and @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the regex delimiter is `#` at the outside of the pattern so you can remove the forward slash here `#^/`

Using [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the separator `|` is the first argument.

As you want to match any of the alternatives at the start of the string, you can use a grouping like a non capture group `(?:...)` to wrap the words.

If there can be nothing directly following the words, you can assert a whitespace boundary to the right with `(?!\S)` meaning that there should not be a non whitespace char directly to the right of the current position.

To make the pattern case insensitive, you can append `i`

The generated pattern looks like this:

```
^(?:XL|L|M|S|XS)(?!\S)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Imgj6/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/hmFFr).

A code example

```
$tallas = '#^(?:' . implode('|', array("XL", "L", "M", "S", "XS")) . ')(?!\S)#i';

$variablenames =  [
    "Marron",
    "m",
    "M"
];

foreach ($variablenames as $variablename) {
    if (preg_match($tallas, $variablename, $matchesatr)) {
        $opciones = "Tallas";
    } else {
        $opciones = "Opciones";
    }
    echo $opciones . PHP_EOL;    
}
```

Output

```
Opciones
Tallas
Tallas
```